# MySQL Conditional Insert on Duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I have an example table with 3 fields where adhex is the primary key.  At the moment I am using ASP and a recordset and it is VERY slow and need to move to a PHP and faster system.  I have been recommended the INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE which works great!

However I want the update to be conditional and cannot work it out!

So far I have the below which doesn't work at all!

What I need to happen is on the update ONLY update the reg and mtime if the mtime in the values is > the one in the table.  I'm sure this is a simple one but I can't work out the conditional part even looking at some examples.

```
INSERT INTO testTable (adhex,reg,mtime) 
VALUES ('00B0BA','reg-1','1294129605') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE reg='ZsS-SLD' 
  CASE 
    WHEN mtime < values(mtime) THEN values(mtime) 
  END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a closer look at the syntax for [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). After `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` comes a sequence of *column* = *expression* statements. Try something like:

```
INSERT INTO testTable (adhex,reg,mtime) 
VALUES ('00B0BA','reg-1','1294129605') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE reg=IF(mtime < VALUES(mtime), 'ZsS-SLD', reg), 
  mtime=IF(mtime < VALUES(mtime), VALUES(mtime), mtime)
```

Comment: Actually I see, two different if statments and then inserting values!  Is there a way to block this into a single if and then run a standard update statement?

Comment: No, the syntax doesn't allow it. You can't set a column in an expression, and (as stated before) you must follow `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` with *column* = *expression*.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how `CASE` works. It returns a value, not a piece of SQL code.

```
Insert into testTable (adhex,reg,mtime)
VALUES ('00B0BA','reg-1','1294129605')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE reg=/*'ZsS-SLD'*/ CASE -- Note the commented out value
    WHEN mtime < values(mtime) THEN values(mtime)
    -- Notice there's not ELSE: you'll get NULL if condition is not matched
END
```

Comment: I get an error saying reg should not be null now, how would I go about updating the reg (and any other fields) in the same query?

Comment: Just set a proper value in the ELSE clause and update as many columns as you need.