# Mysql - INSERT from SELECT with conditional ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql

I'm reading about conditional updates on duplicate key based on IF statements - e.g., [MySQL Conditional Insert on Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593031/mysql-conditional-insert-on-duplicate).

I'm trying to do something similar, but within an insert from a select:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO data1 (id, date, quantity)
SELECT id, date, quantity
FROM other_table
WHERE date = '2015-03-01'
AND id=123
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
quantity = IF(quantity IS NULL, VALUES(quantity), quantity)
```

However, this generates an error:

```
#1052 - Column 'quantity' in field list is ambiguous
```

I can't quite figure out how to tell MySQL which 'quantity' field is which in order to resolve the ambiguity problem.  Adding aliases to each table doesn't seem to help (calling data1 'd' throws a different error).

Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: use table aliases on data1 and other_table to remove the ambiguity and qualify their respective columns with their table aliases.

Comment: I think you should use other_table.quantity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should qualify the references to the `quantity` field that belongs to table `data1` in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` part of the query:

```
INSERT INTO data1 (id, date, quantity)
SELECT id, date, quantity
FROM other_table
WHERE date = '2015-03-01'
AND id=123
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
quantity = IF(data1.quantity IS NULL, VALUES(quantity), data1.quantity)
```

A shorter way to write this `IF()` expression is to use function [`IFNULL()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) or [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
quantity = IFNULL(data1.quantity, VALUES(quantity))
```

or

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
quantity = COALESCE(data1.quantity, VALUES(quantity))
```

Also, there is no need to use `IGNORE`. The errors that `IGNORE` converts to warnings does not happen any more because of the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause.

---

## 2024 update

The [`VALUES()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values) has been deprecated in MySQL v8.0.20 and will be removed in the future. Since MySQL v8.0.19, aliases can be provided for the row to be inserted and also for each of its columns.

Using the new features, for MySQL v8.0.19 and newer use this query:

```sql
INSERT INTO data1 (id, date, quantity) AS new_row
SELECT id, date, quantity
FROM other_table
WHERE date = '2015-03-01'
AND id=123
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
quantity = IFNULL(data1.quantity, new_row.quantity)
```

The `AS new_row` alias provides a name for the row to be inserted; the name can be used instead of the deprecated `VALUES()` function to access the columns of the row to be inserted.

Check the [documentation of `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) for details and examples.

Comment: Thanks for the note on `IGNORE`. That makes sense, but I never considered it.

Comment: Didn't know you could disambiguate columns that way. Thanks for saving me lots of frustration, @axiac!

Comment: `VALUES()` was deprecated as of 8.0.20, but it as of 8.0.19 you can use an alias instead ([link to manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html))

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't know to which quantity column you are referring since it is present in both `data1` and `other_table` tables.

You have to use it like this: `other_table.quantity`

Answer (score 0):

Your query will change like this

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO data1 (id, date, quantity)
SELECT id, date, quantity
FROM other_table
WHERE date = '2015-03-01'
AND id=123
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
data1.quantity = IF(other_table.quantity IS NULL,
VALUES(other_table.quantity), other_table.quantity)
```